# Eval and lexical variables

Tags: lisp, eval, common-lisp

I'm doing a small project just for fun, and I added `eval` support for it to make debug easier. But later I found a problem:

```
(let ((x 1))
    (eval (1+ x)))

(defun foo (x form)
    (eval form))
(foo 1 '(1+ x))
```

Code above won't work. Could someone please explain why and how to work it around? Thanks very much.

Comment: see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm

Comment: It is unclear why you would add `EVAL` to *make debug* easier. That makes very little sense.

Comment: @RainerJoswig It may provide me with a REPL-like facility while the software is running.

Comment: For what? Lisp already has a REPL. And a Debugger. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @RainerJoswig My software is a server and it's listening, I'm not able to use the REPL...

Comment: Then you should run your server in a separate lisp process so the REPL is still accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, though

```
(let ((x 1))
  (eval (1+ x)))
```

may look like it does work (it certainly does something), it is likely not doing, what you intend it to do. `eval` is a regular function, so it receives its arguments evaluated by the caller. Effectively, you are calling `eval` with an integer value of `2` -- which is then "evaluated" (since integers are self-quoting) to a result value of `2`.

In

```
(defun foo (x form)
  (eval form))
```

it's easier to diagnose the failure. Run-time lexical bindings are not first-class objects, but something maintained by the interpreter/compiler behind the scenes. Regular functions (like `eval`) cannot access lexical variables defined at their call-sites.

One work-around would be to use special variables:

```
(defun foo (x form)
  (declare (special x))
  (eval form))
```

The declaration tells your lisp implementation, that `x` should be dynamically bound within its scope.