# Behavior of let, eval, and quote

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I was trying to understand the behavior of `let`.
Why does case2 throw me an error?

```
;; case1: worked fine.
(let ((NF 5)) NF)
5

;; case2: got an error
(let ((NF 5)) (eval 'NF))
error: The variable NF is unbound
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eval and lexical variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312607/eval-and-lexical-variables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EVAL` doesn't have access to lexical variables. The [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm#eval) says:

> Evaluates form in the current dynamic environment and the null lexical environment.

If you declare the variable `special` it will work, since this performs a dynamic binding rather than a lexical binding.

```
(let ((NF 5))
  (declare (special NF))
  (eval 'NF))
5
```